# Throwing a Mono.error for Kotlin Non-Null Assertion

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-null-safety

I have written a function, in Kotlin, where I've used the non null assertion in the method signature as follows:

```
saveEntity(param1!!, param2!!)
 .onErrorResume {
    logger.error("Exception caught", it)
    Mono.just(someObject)
 }
```

Just for reference, the `saveEntity` method returns a `Mono<someObject>`. The issue is, when **param1** or **param2** is null and the code throws a NullPointerException, it's not a Mono and I'm not able to handle it in `onErrorResume`. Is there a way to throw a Mono.error() in the function call itself using any ternary type operations so that this exception can be caught in onErrorResume()?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Kotlin, you could write a lambda utility for this, along the lines of:

```kotlin
fun <R> monoCatching(job: () -> R): Mono<R> = try {
    Mono.just(job())
} catch (t: Throwable) {
    Mono.error(t)
}
```

Note that I have not checked whether this compiles, but tweaked, it should do what you need:

```kotlin
monoCatching { saveEntity(param1!!, param2!!) }.onErrorResume ...
```

The reason this works is that the null check is done inside the lambda expression and thus is inside the inner try-catch block. Be aware that this requires `param1` and `param2` to be (at least) effectively final.